# Why QObject::disconnect(const QMetaObject::Connection &connection) takes const argument with intention to modify it?

Tags: c++, qt

`static bool QObject::disconnect(const QMetaObject::Connection &connection)`

This method is meant to disconnect an existing `Connection` object with intention to modify it. So why is the function argument declared as a **`const`** reference?

In the source code implementation (`qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp`), you can find the unavoidable `const_cast`:

```
const_cast<QMetaObject::Connection &>(connection).d_ptr = 0;
```

What is the advantage of marking the function argument as `const` when the function's purpose is to modify it?

Comment: if `d_ptr` were declared as `mutable`, the `const_cast` would not be needed anymore, as a  `const` method can modify `mutable` members.

Comment: Thanks for edit @RemyLebeau.Yes `mutable` would make it possible to avoid using `const_cast`. But as a client of the disconnect function, I'd expect the `Connection` to be modified as a result of disconnection.

Comment: The downside of `mutable` would be that *any* `const` method could modify `d_ptr`.  Using `const_cast` without `mutable` instead, this makes it clearer and more explicit that *only* `disconnect()` should be modifying `d_ptr`. Of course, if any other `const` method wanted to modify `d_ptr`, they could just use `const_cast`, too.  But using `const_cast` advertises explicit intent at the individual call sites, whereas `mutable` is less restrictive in that regard.

Comment: The only advantage I see is that this function can be called in a const-context which may be just enough to warrant the const cast.

Comment: You're asking about a living, breathing code base. Usually when such things happen, the reason is simple: the "weird" stuff is a post-hoc fix to an API frozen in its binary-compatible shape. This will be fixed, or otherwise redone for Qt 6 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons are purely historical. The API, as originally conceived, was thought not to need to modify the `Connection` instance while disconnecting it. This has proven to be ill-conceived indeed. Binary compatibility reasons forced the API to remain unchanged. Neither the const-removal in the argument type nor mutable-addition in the field type would be [binary-compatible changes](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B). Relevant excerpt:

> You cannot [...] For existing classes [...] For existing functions of any type [...] change its signature.
>   This includes [...] changing any of the types of the arguments in the parameter list, including changing the const/volatile qualifiers [...]
>
> You cannot [...] For non-static members [...] change the type of the member, except for signedness [...]

[The original implementation](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/79f675a1e0f628bbc25345ebc1eb1f5809166c6b) of the new disconnect API did not modify the `d_ptr`. This caused a memory leak when the `Connection` instance outlived the sender object. [The fix](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/c4f433d581e2d609d2eaecc4e4b999a469950eb3) had to modify the `Connection`'s non-mutable fields, and this `const_cast` was the only way to do it.

The original implementation is from 2011, and predates Qt 5 release, but the fix went into Qt 5.0.1, in 2012: at that point the binary compatibility had to be retained.

Comment: Thanks @kuba, in such cases when implementation outlives interface, would it make sense to create an overloaded function (in this case without const) and mark the existing one deprecated?

That wouldn't break binary compatibility and according to linked document with _the do's and don'ts_ it shouldn't break source compatibility either because the function is already overloaded.

Comment: @Palec Of course it makes sense. This could be your first contribution to Qt :)